# Manipulating a random variable that is uniformly distributed

Tags: probability-distributions

I had to answer the following question: $X$ has a uniform distribution between 0 and 1. What is the distribution of $X^3$?

Now the pdf for X is simply:

$f(x)=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1, &\mbox{if } 0\leq x \leq1 \\
  0, & \mbox{otherwise}
 \end{array}
\right.$

After substituting $x^3$ for $x$ in the cdf for $X$ and then differentiating it with respect to $x$, I got the following pdf for $X$:

$f(x)=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac 13x^{-\frac{2}{3}}, &\mbox{if } 0\leq x \leq1 \\
  0, & \mbox{otherwise}
 \end{array}
\right.$

Is this correct?

Now, the last part of the question asks "What is the distribution of $X^3$? Is my answer sufficient or does this pdf correspond to a particular distribution? Because it doesn't ring a bell for me.

Thanks

Comment: You are correct. For the last part, I don't recognize it. I'm guess it is enougth. Explicitely the distribution is $F_{X^3}(x)=\sqrt[x]{x}1_{[0,1]}(x)+1_{(1\infty)}(x)$

Comment: The distribution is completely determined by its PDF which you calculated correctly except that  $0\leq x\leq 1$ should be replaced by $0<x\leq1$. If "they" make troubles about the absence of a label then protest against that firmly. Also in my head bells are not ringing.

Comment: Can you please explain why it is strict inequality after the 0? Thanks for your help, much appreciated

Comment: function $x^{-\frac23}$ is not *defined* at $x=0$.

Comment: Sorry - head is in the clouds. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

It looks right, and it is a [$\text{Beta}(1/3,1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution);
$$f_X(x) = \frac{\Gamma(1/3+1)}{\Gamma(1/3)\Gamma(1)} x^{1/3-1}(1-x)^{1-1} = \frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}$$
over $(0,1]$.

Comment: Over $(0,1]$ you mean. Actually I hoped for the OP that a name would be lacking :(.

Comment: @drhab Yes, you are right. I was sloppy. At least it is not an obscure  distribution. :)

Comment: Also termed a PowerFunction(1/3) with domain of support on (0,1):  $$f(x) = a x^{a - 1}    \quad   \text{ for }  0<x<1$$ and parameter $a>0$

Comment: @wolfies _That's_ obscure :p

Comment: Isn't your fraction of Gamma functions upside down? I'm pretty sure $\beta (\frac 13,1)=3$. In that case, what is the distribution?

Comment: @VladimirNabokov It is a [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), not to be confused with the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. But isn't true that the Beta distribution is only defined on (0,1)?

Comment: Or does it not make a difference since it is a continuous distribution?

Comment: @VladimirNabokov I do not believe that it should make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the probability density function (pdf).$$\begin{align}f_{X^3}(z) = & ~ f_X(z^{1/3})~\lvert(z^{1/3})'\rvert \\[1ex] = & ~ \dfrac{ z^{-2/3} }{3} ~\raise{0.4ex}\chi_{z\in(0;1]}\end{align}$$

You can also integrate to obtain the Cumulative Distribution Function:

$$F_{X^3}(z) =z^{1/3}~\raise{0.5ex}\chi_{z\in[0;1)}+ \raise{0.5ex}\chi_{z\in[1;\infty)}$$

This isn't any particularly named distribution, except perhaps a member of the  family of Beta distributions.